# Stop a while loop when the counter reaches a certain number

Tags: php, counting

I'm having trouble to make a 'counting' system in PHP. I would like it to be like this:

1. Clark
2. Maikel
3. Steven
4. .....

My problem is that I can't make this because the names are coming through a while loop, so I don't know how to make it now. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
    while($score = $highscore->fetch_array())
    {
        // Systeem voor levels.
        if($score['clicks'] >= 0 && $score['clicks'] <= 49)
        {
            $level = 'Level 1';
        }
        elseif($score['clicks'] >= 50 && $score['clicks'] <= 99)
        {
            $level = 'Level 2';
        }
        else if($score['clicks'] >= 100 && $score['clicks'] <= 199)
        {
            $level = 'Level 3';
        }
        else if($score['clicks'] >= 200 && $score['clicks'] <= 349)
        {
            $level = 'Level 4';
        }
        else if($score['clicks'] >= 350 && $score['clicks'] <= 499)
        {
            $level = 'Level 5';
        }
        else if($score['clicks'] >= 500 && $score['clicks'] <= 749)
        {
            $level = 'Level 6';
        }
        else if($score['clicks'] >= 750 && $score['clicks'] <= 999)
        {
            $level = 'Level 7';
        }
        else if($score['clicks'] >= 1000 && $score['clicks'] <= 1499)
        {
            $level = 'Level 8';
        }
        else if($score['clicks'] >= 1500 && $score['clicks'] <= 1999)
        {
             $level = 'Level 9';
        }
        else if($score['clicks'] >= 2000 && $score['clicks'] <= 2999)
        {
             $level = 'Level 10';
        }
        else if($score['clicks'] == 3000)
        {
             $level = 'Level 11';
        }
        else if($score['clicks']> 3000)
        {
             $level= 'Level ' . floor(($score['clicks']/1000)+8);
        }
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $score['name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $score['clicks']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $level; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

So my question is how can I make a counting system that count up till 100? It needs to go before .

Sorry for the bad English, thank you for helping!

Comment: You add a variable `$i = 0;` for example in front of the loop, increment it in the loop and echo it along with the rest of your stuff at the bottom in the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;
    while($score = $highscore->fetch_array())
    {
        $counter++;

        //Your content

        if ( $counter >= 100 ) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

This should break your while when it reaches 100.

Comment: Yeah thank you! I didn't thought it would be needed to put $counter before the while loop, that was why I was getting the same number by every name, again thank you!

Comment: Not a problem, always happy to help.